# ranking within MDX

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx, mdx-query

I have this MDX Query:

```
WITH
MEMBER [COUNT_RANK] AS
   RANK(([TKT].[SP].CURRENTMEMBER,
[TKT].[SA].CURRENTMEMBER) ,
[TKT].[SP].CURRENTMEMBER
*[TKT].[SA].[SA]
)
SELECT {
[COUNT_RANK],
[Measures].[TKT Count],
[Measures].[Est Hours]
} ON 0,
ORDER ({[TKT].[SP].[SP]} * {[TKT].[SA].[SA]}, [Measures].[TKT Count], DESC)
ON 1
FROM Ops
```

the issue I have is that While the `COUNT_RANK` works and provides a 1-to-n value of ranking per `SP` for each `SA`, I need the order of the rank based on `TKT Count desc`.  Meaning for `rank = 1`, then that SP*SA must have the highest number of TKTs.

Right now the result is random TKT Counts for the RANKING.  how do I make the RANK go based on TKT Count DESC?

This is for SQL Server 2016 SSAS.  Thanks.

Comment: Did you try an `ORDER` in the `WITH
MEMBER [COUNT_RANK]` declaration?

Comment: no.  How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

From the [MSDN Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/mdx/rank-mdx?view=sql-server-2017), you should create an ordered set before you declare the RANK() member, and use RANK function on the ordered set.

Here's their example:

```
WITH   
SET OrderedCities AS Order  
   ([Geography].[City].[City].members  
   , [Measures].[Reseller Sales Amount], BDESC  
   )  
MEMBER [Measures].[City Rank] AS Rank  
   ([Geography].[City].CurrentMember, OrderedCities)  
SELECT {[Measures].[City Rank],[Measures].[Reseller Sales Amount]}  ON 0   
,Order  
   ([Geography].[City].[City].MEMBERS  
   ,[City Rank], ASC)  
    ON 1  
FROM [Adventure Works]
```